# Getting value from modified radio button by onclick or just click event gives undef answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I am trying to create a situation where any 'button' will have javascript obtain the values directly anytime it is clicked on. For example:

`<label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pushme(this.value)"><input 
   type="radio" name="reps" id="here" value="20" /> 20 </label>`

```
function pushme(e){
console.log("Button is pressed!" + e)
}
```

I also tried the following:

`<label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pushme()"><input type="radio" name="reps" id="here" value="20" /> 20 </label>`

with

`function pushme(){
  var test = $(this).val;
  console.log("Testing this" + test)
}`

Other methods I tried:
`$("btn").click(()=>{console.log("Print this stuff" + this.val())` with many variations such as val without (), value(), value, e.val with input 'e' in function, etc...only "Print this stuff" part worked, and if undef didn't work, it causes major error in console.

My goal is to be able to quickly get the value of the pressed button, and then immediately display it (the display aspect is not part of this question, how to get the value is the problem right now.)  Thanks.

Comment: *"with many variations such as val without (), value(), value, e.val with input 'e' in function"* - `.value` is a standard form element property and must be used without parentheses and called directly on DOM nodes, *not* called on jQuery objects. `.val()` is a jQuery method, must be used with parentheses, and can only be called on jQuery objects. In both cases you need a reference to the input element itself, not to its associated label.

Comment: Why dont you just set click listeners in your js file instead of in an html attribute? All of this could have been avoided. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the event listener to the input.

```js
function pushme(value) {
  console.log("Button is pressed!" + value)
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-primary"><input 
   type="radio" name="reps" id="here" value="20" onclick="pushme(this.value)" /> 20 </label>
```

If you want it to listen for any button then you can attach the event listener dynamically via JavaScript:

```js
function pushme() {
  let value = this.value
  console.log("Button is pressed!" + value)
}

document.querySelectorAll('.btn input')
  .forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', pushme)
  })
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-primary"><input 
   type="radio" name="reps" id="here" value="20" /> 20 </label>

<label class="btn btn-primary"><input 
   type="radio" name="reps" id="there" value="30" /> 30 </label>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working.  I have tried both methods.   See https://codepen.io/pkshreeman/pen/ModpPm?editors=1010  I wonder if there is something going on with Bootstrap 4, or CodePen?   The value is undefined and functionally different.  I have to put the onclick inside label for it to work.  If I put that inside input, it would not trigger.

Comment: @Dr.PaulKennethShreeman Change the value inside `pushme` to `event.target.querySelector('input').value`

Answer (score 1):

I saw your code on https://codepen.io/pkshreeman/pen/ModpPm?editors=1010. Modify pushme function :

```
function pushme(event) {
   let value = event.target.innerText;
   console.log("Button is pressed! " + value)
}
```

Comment: This answer offers an excellent workaround, and it worked great!  However, the problem was to obtain the set value of the button which the earlier one addressed by using querySelector('input').value.  Thank you as this will come useful for me in other situation!